# Can a partitioned table span on multiple files across different file groups?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, partitioning

In SQL Server 2008 and above, if a table is partitioned, can it span across multiple files across multiple filegroups?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can. ([BOL reference on Partitioned Tables and Indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787.aspx))

> SQL Server supports table and index partitioning. The data of partitioned tables and indexes is divided into **units that can be spread across more than one filegroup** in a database.